# Is $(m \Leftrightarrow m) \Leftrightarrow (m \Rightarrow m)$ a tautology, contradiction or contingent?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Is this a Tautology, contradiction or contingent?

$(m \Leftrightarrow m) \Leftrightarrow (m \Rightarrow m)$

My answer is that It is a tautology. But what is yours?

Can someone please explain with a truth table? 
Thank you so much!!!!!

Comment: What does $\square$ mean?

Comment: Sorry didnt understand you

Comment: Why are people in the answers assuming $\square$ means $\iff$?

Comment: but no one used that? Im sorry i might be missing something ..

Comment: The connective I see on my screen is $\square$. It shows the same in two different browsers. In the edit window it also shows $\square$.

Comment: oh ok. Strange. Anyway. With my question - Do I need to have 4 columns in my truth table? 
Which are : m, m⟺m, m⟹m, (m⟺m)⟺(m⟹m)

Comment: You need only three columns: $m, m\square m$ and $(m\square m)\square (m\square m)$.

Comment: And they have values T,F,T,F? But how does the other columns work?

Comment: I can't answer that because I don't know what the connective $\square$ means.

Comment: it is - 
(m doublesidearrow m) doublesidearrow (m rightsidearrow m)

:)

Comment: @GitGud: This square is supposed to be a $\Leftrightarrow$, but he didn't type it via TeX, but used some weird Unicode symbol, which you most likely can not display because your system (not browser) lacks support for some (unimportant) Unicode blocks.

Comment: @Tomas Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
m  |  m <--> m | m --> m | (m <-> m) <--> (m --> m) 
T  |     T     |    T    |             T            
F  |     T     |    T    |             T
```

Note that each of $m \rightarrow m$ and $m \leftrightarrow m$ is a tautology (always true, regardless of the truth value of $m$), and hence, $$(m \leftrightarrow m) \leftrightarrow (m \rightarrow m)$$

is necessarily a tautology, as well, which means the following equivalence necessarily holds: $$(m \leftrightarrow m) \leftrightarrow (m \rightarrow m) \equiv T$$

Comment: Thank you so much. Is there a way we can prove this by any other Rules such that we can derive it to T or F? IT should only be T i think.

Comment: Yes, it is true, always true (since it is a tautology, which we've shown above). The columns show only $T$ above. Perhaps you're confusing my column breaks $|$ with an I? The last column to the right shows that the proposition is true when $m$ is true, and the proposition is true when $m$ is false. So it doesn't matter whether $m$ is true or false: the proposition is true in either case. Hence $(m \leftrightarrow m) \leftrightarrow (m \rightarrow m) \equiv T$

Comment: Yes! Makes sense. Thank you Kind person! 
There is another thing I wanted to ask you and that is - In order to prove this from LHS to RHS - That answer will also be T. Right? To do that we have to use Rules like Distributive, Commutative? But I dont understand how I will prove this theoretically. I understood the turth table and the concept, but in written how can we prove this is right.

Comment: @amWhy: Nice discussion and answer +1

Comment: The column break didnt even come on my browser initially and had one 'I' next to T. It all makes sense.

Comment: @user2923027 I've added an answer below to show a way to prove it theoretically given the axiom set I've indicated there.

Answer (score 0):

It is tauntology.

```
p  q  |  p->q
T  T  |   T
T  F  |   F
F  T  |   T
F  F  |   T
```

You always have the same value, that is m
$$
(m\implies m)
$$
is always true when the inputs are same.

Comment: You are right. This is tauntology.

Comment: "tauntology" strikes me as the "study of taunting"! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In [Polish notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation) we can prove this from the following axioms under the rule of detachment:

{C$\alpha$$\beta$, $\alpha$} $\vdash$ $\beta$.

"C" symbolizes the conditional, and "E" the bi-conditional or equivalence operator.  The well-formed formula has Emm on the left, Cmm on the right, and reads EEmmCmm.

Axiom 1-CmCnm   Recursive Letter Prefixing

Axiom 2-CCmCnoCCmnCmo  Self-Distribution

Axiom 3-CCmnCCnmEmn

The notation $\alpha$/$\beta$ indicates that the lower case letter $\alpha$ gets substituted uniformly with the well-formed formula $\beta$.  The numeral symbols refer to the well-formed formulas.  * functions as a separator, and - serves as a sign of detachment.  So, 3 m/n * C2-4 would mean that in well-formed formula 3 we will substitute all instances of "m" with n, it has the same form (it is "the same" well-formed formula) as the well-formed formula as a conditional with 2 as the antecedent, and 4 the consequent.  We will thus detach well-formed formula 4.

```
  2 o/m * 4
```

4 CCmCnmCCmnCmm

```
  4 * C1-5
```

5 CCmnCmm

```
  5 n/Cnm * C1-6
```

6 Cmm

```
  3 n/m*C6-7
```

7 CCmmEmm

```
  7*C6-8
```

8 Emm

```
  1 m/Cmm, n/Emm * C6-9
```

9 CEmmCmm

```
  3 m/Emm, n/Cmm * C9-10
```

10 CCCmmEmmEEmmCmm

```
  10 * C7-11
```

11 EEmmCmm